# Recently can't connect to my NAS via HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, self-signed, synology

I have a [Synology NAS DiskStation DS2415+.](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS2415+) When I bought it several years ago, I followed the setup instructions and created a self-stamped certificate which worked and even allowed me to remotely connect to my NAS via HTTPS.

Recently I changed some settings following the Synology's "[Security Advisor](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/Tutorial/secure_your_nas)" which is an automatic tool which scans all settings and recommend changes to secure it.

Following the recommendations of the said tool, I made some the reuqired changes, mostly in the **Network Settings** and **Security Settings**, but now I now can't use [Quick Connect](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/connection_quickconnect) without getting a warning. In case any of you is familiar with this issue, I do hope there is a way to use HTTPS and not HTTP, either with a self stamp SSL or a purchased one. When I inquired about purchasing an SSL, I am told that it would be impossible to use an SSL without a dedicated domain for that SSL, but that's a side issue because originally my NAS worked and was remotely accessed via a [self stamped certificate](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html).

[image]

Comment: Have you simple clicked the `Advanced` button? Once clicking that, it wil reveal a `Proceed Anyway` button. This error is simply telling you that the certificated you are using are untrusted, but you already know that seeing as you said you self-signed them. As long as you trust it, click through the warning.

Comment: Not last time I checked @Matt, they’re saving us from ourselves now. You can always type “badidea” on that page though, that’ll let you through. Not really sure what this has to do with programming though...

Comment: @MattClark - I did and it worked, however in the past, thanks to the self stamped certificate the screen (shown in my question) didn't appear and its quite annoying...

Comment: If you download a copy of the CA that was used to sign the certificate, and install it into your browser, the warnings will go away.

Comment: I tried that but I still get that "not secure" indication.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by the following steps:

**Creating a Self Stamped SSL (done in 2 steps)**
1. Go to Control Panel -> Security -> Certificate -> CSR
[image]

2. Generate the CSR and download it. Use your user name as the **Common name**.
   [image]
3. Go again to Certificate -> CSR and this time select **Sign Certificate Signing Request**. You will then be asked to select the .csr file from before, and as a result, the certificate will be downloaded.
4. Go to your browser and import this certificate. (Thanks @Matt Clark !)
5. In my case, only after going to Chrome -> Settings -> Advance and selecting **Reset Settings to Default**, it worked.
   [image]

I can now connect to my NAS using [QuickConnect](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_make_Synology_NAS_accessible_over_the_Internet) and using HTTPS.
[image]